# Ошибка при использовании модуля pkg.refresh_db

Tags: saltstack

При создании собственного sls  файла и попытки синхронизировать его на миньоны, отвечает с ошибкой:

> ERROR: Error occurred while generating repo db. Additional info follows:
>
> ```
> failed:
>     1
> failed_list:
>     ----------
>     salt-winrepo-ng\wget.sls:
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number full_name is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number installer is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number install_flags is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number uninstaller is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number uninstall_flags is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number msiexec is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number locale is not defined as a dictionary
>         - package 'wget', repo data for version number reboot is not defined as a dictionary"
> ```

Содержание SLS такое:

```
# just 32-bit x86 installer available
{% if grains['cpuarch'] == 'AMD64' %}
    {% set PROGRAM_FILES = "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" %}
{% else %}
    {% set PROGRAM_FILES = "%ProgramFiles%" %}
{% endif %}
wget:
    full_name: 'wget'
    installer: 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe'
    install_flags: '/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART'
    uninstaller: '{{ PROGRAM_FILES }}\GnuWin32\uninstall\unins001.exe'
    uninstall_flags: '/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART'
    msiexec: False
    locale: en_US
    reboot: Fals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по содержимому приведённого sls-файла, это «package definition for [windows software repository](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html)».

если посмотреть на [пример такого описания](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html#creating-a-package-definition-sls-file):

```
firefox:
  '17.0.1':
    installer: 'salt://win/repo/firefox/English/Firefox Setup 17.0.1.exe'
    full_name: Mozilla Firefox 17.0.1 (x86 en-US)
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False
    install_flags: '-ms'
    uninstaller: '%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Mozilla Firefox/uninstall/helper.exe'
    uninstall_flags: '/S'
```

то сразу видно, что в вашем файле пропущен один пункт в иерархии, с номером версии.

т.е., должно быть не:

```
wget:
    full_name: 'wget'
    ...
```

а:

```
wget:
  'номер-версии':
    full_name: 'wget'
    ...
```